# How to use gvNix Typical security? Getting started does not work

Tags: java, roo, gvnix

One of my requirements is to implement authentication while developing with Spring Roo.
I found the gvNix and it's Typical security and it looks very promising.

Yet, following the example at [Typical security - getting started](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-typical-security/wiki/GettingStarted) I could not get it to work.

```
project --topLevelPackage com.testproject2 --projectName TestProject2
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
typicalsecurity setup

<Exit gvNIX>>
mvn tomcat:run
```

Question: could anyone give me a basic.
Any help welcomed!

Below is the content of the command line console.

```
D:\Source\TypicalSecurity>\Tools\gvNIX-1.4.1\bin\gvnix.bat
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /    gvNIX 1.4.1.RELEASE distribution
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.3.1.RELEASE [rev 8cb81a3]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo-gvNIX> project --topLevelPackage com.testproject2 --projectName TestProject2
Created ROOT\pom.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\log4j.properties
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT\applicationContext.xml
roo-gvNIX> persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\dynamic-configuration.xml
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT\database.properties
Updated SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT\applicationContext.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\META-INF\persistence.xml
Updated ROOT\pom.xml [added dependencies org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.2.9, org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final, org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final, org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final, commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.2.Final, javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA, javax.transaction:jta:1.1, org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${spring.version}, org.springframework:spring-orm:${spring.version}, commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.6, commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4]
roo-gvNIX> typicalsecurity setup
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserIntegrationTest.java
Updated ROOT\pom.xml [added dependency net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:0.0.7]
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_ToString.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleDataOnDemand.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleIntegrationTest.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_ToString.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\RoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\Role_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleDataOnDemand.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleIntegrationTest.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_ToString.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole.java
Updated SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRoleDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_JavaBean.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Finder.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User.java
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\User_Roo_Finder.aj
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\testproject2\domain\UserRole_Roo_Finder.aj
Command 'web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserController --backingType ~.domain.User' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
Command 'web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.RoleController --backingType ~.domain.Role' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
Command 'web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserRoleController --backingType ~.domain.UserRole' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
Command 'security setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\forgotpassword
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\forgotpassword\views.xml
Undo create ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\forgotpassword\views.xml
Undo create ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\forgotpassword
Could not acquire D:\Source\TypicalSecurity\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties
~.domain.UserRole roo-gvNIX> exit
D:\Source\TypicalSecurity>mvn tomcat:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom (6 KB at 14.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
...
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/tanesha/recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j/0.0.7/recaptcha4j-0.0.7.jar (11 KB at 196.2 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar (632 KB at 1585.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.2.Final/hibernate-validator-4.3.2.Final.jar (474 KB at 1467.2 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar (698 KB at 1453.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar (5131 KB at 1960.6 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) @ TestProject2 ---
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.1/aspectjtools-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.1/aspectjtools-1.8.1.pom (1022 B at 1.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.1/aspectjtools-1.8.1.jar
Downloaded: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.1/aspectjtools-1.8.1.jar (10721 KB at 972.1 KB/sec)
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:test-compile (default) @ TestProject2 ---
[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.testproject2.domain.Role [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.testproject2.domain.User [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.testproject2.domain.UserRole [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestProject2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ TestProject2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ TestProject2 <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ TestProject2 ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-09T18:59:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/44M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\Source\TypicalSecurity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This add-on includes part of web pages, so requires the web mvc layer installed. Try this commands sequence:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.testproject2 --projectName TestProject2
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
// You should include any simple entity
web mvc setup
web mvc scaffold all --package com.testproject2.web
typicalsecurity setup
```

If you want a full example about this feature try this:

```
// First run the petclinc roo example
script --file clinic.roo
// install typical security assets
typicalsecurity setup
```

Good luck!!